# Using SVG Images in HTML?

Tags: html, svg

I want to use a SVG picture in my HTML file, but that image doesn't load.

I tried to use the `img` and `iframe` tags.

http://cld.persiangig.com/dl/dHo6d/Rg9Myk2bCv/alert.svg

Comment: Show the actula markup you tried an identify what happened in what browser(s).

Comment: I think you can embed svg images as `object` or `img` tags, and even just include the `svg` tag itself. What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
<object data="http://www.broken-links.com/tests/images/heart-tree.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

Or use :

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="http://www.broken-links.com/tests/images/heart-tree.svg" />
```

**Update** : instead of your comments in persian language and question about to set svg image to background of a div :

```
div {    
    background-image: url("http://www.broken-links.com/tests/images/heart-tree.svg");  
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/farshadajdar/9n6cbcb5/)

More info at [**add-svg-to-web-page article**](http://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/)

Comment: فرشاد حالا اگه بخوام توی بک گراند بگذارمش چطوریه؟

Comment: اون مقاله که لینکشو گذاشتم مطالعه کن تقریبا همه مواردی که پرسیدی رو داره

Comment: This does not work for the case presented.

Comment: No Me Dear Friend @JukkaK.Korpela this code is correct

Comment: my answer is correct ! here is jsfiddle demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xwaLkp1L/1/)

Comment: No, the image does not show. The `embed` element depends on plugins and might work in some special environment, but not here. The `object` element is not present in the jsfiddle at all and simply shows the fallback text ”Your SVG”,

Comment: @moeinomidi برات لینک نمونه بک گراند رو هم گذاشتم.

Comment: The question was not about a background image, and referring to backgrounds here is just confusing.

Comment: dear JukkaK.Korpela , are you know persian language ? @moeinomidi in comments asked about how to set svg to background of a div. and I have updated my answer

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i asked him about background in persian language but you dont khow this language! **:(**

Comment: @moeinomidi, what makes you think I don’t know Persian? Anyway, what matters is what is asked in the question itself and whether the answers address and solve the issues presented there. This is not a chat.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela this is your problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the HTTP headers, which were not included in the question and can only be retrieved using the URL given, which may stop working or change the way it works at any moment without notice. But for the record, these are the response headers as of now:

```
HTTP/1.1·200·OK(CR)(LF)
Server:·nginx/1.4.7(CR)(LF)
Date:·Sun,·24·Aug·2014·12:20:31·GMT(CR)(LF)
Content-Type:·application/octet-stream(CR)(LF)
Content-Length:·550(CR)(LF)
Last-Modified:·Sun,·24·Aug·2014·12:12:03·GMT(CR)(LF)
Connection:·close(CR)(LF)
Cache-Control:·public,·must-revalidate(CR)(LF)
Content-disposition:·attachment;·filename="alert.svg"(CR)(LF)
ETag:·"53f9d693-226"(CR)(LF)
Accept-Ranges:·bytes(CR)(LF)
(CR)(LF)
```

Thus, the resource is identified as application/octet-stream (which means lump of binary data in unspecified format), and the server asks the client to store the resource as a file, under the name alert.svg.

You need to change the way the server works for .svg files, making it to announce their content type as image/svg+xml (without a `Content-Disposition` header). That way, the situation will only depend on the browser support to SVG images.